# node not able to retain its Visited info

Tags: c, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement breadth first search in C, but while transversing I'm encountering an problem, the node is not able to retain it's visited info,

here is the code of my bfs function.

here is the adjacency list.

```
0->1->2->3->
|
V
1->0->4->5->
|
V
2->0->6->7->
|
V
3->0->7->
|
V
4->1->
|
V
5->1->
|
V
6->2->
|
V
7->2->3->
```

**`here rollsTemp, rollsTemp1 are pointing towards first element of the adj list`**

```
void bfs(struct hack *rollsTemp, struct hack *rollsTemp1){
    struct hack *head = rollsTemp; // we take a temp head

    enqueue(rollsTemp1->node);  //we enqueue 0 and mark it as visited
    rollsTemp1->V = 1;  

    char Vertex;

    while (g_front <= g_rear){  // until the queue is empty 

        while (rollsTemp != 0){  // rollsTemp is an iterator travells vertically untill the vertex is found

            if (rollsTemp == head) {  // only dequeue when the iterator is at the top, it prevents dequeueing on very iteration for searching

                    Vertex = dequeue();     
                    p("%c ", Vertex);  // prints 0

                }

            if (rollsTemp->node == Vertex){ // here we find that 0 is on the first row of the adj list               
                rollsTemp1 = rollsTemp; // we set another pointer to transverse horizontally

                while (rollsTemp1 != 0){


                    if (rollsTemp1->V == 0){

                        rollsTemp1->V = 1;

                        enqueue(rollsTemp1->node);

                        rollsTemp1 = rollsTemp1->next;

                        } else {

                            rollsTemp1 = rollsTemp1->next;

                        }       

                }           

                rollsTemp = head;   

            } else {

                    rollsTemp = rollsTemp->down;

                }


        }   

}

}
```

1. so I start with 0 enqueue it and mark it as visited, and go to 1, 2, 3 mark them visited and enqueue them,
2. after that i dequeue 1 and search the other nodes of 1, i.e. 0, 4, 5
3. here is the adj list of it 1->0->4->5->
4. so when I start traversing in this list, it first sees 1 (although we not need to check 1 because it is the parent node now, but it was marked visited earlier" so out program must ignore it), and when the "if" block of visited check comes, it enters it. the if block is if (node->V != 1) then mark it visited and enqueue it

i further enqueues 0 also, and we know that we have already marked 1 as visited i.e node->V = 1, then why their node is not able to retain this information, is this have to do somethings with pointers? or the information is getting lost somewhere?

here is my struct.

```
struct hack{

    char node;
    struct hack *next;
    struct hack *down;   
    int V;    //we mark it 1 for visited and 0 is by defaulreat
};
```

any help why a node is not able to retain it's info about `V` is it have to do something with pointers?

Comment: No offense but I guess you can get a lot of help from this. [mcve]

Comment: okay i'll try to minimize it

Comment: You have to provide actual code so that we can run it on our machine and get the problem you have told. Now if you have 10 different functions which you dont use then don't post them. Just give the code which we can run and check whether we will get the error.

Comment: i did the same earlier mate, and it was only one function

Comment: i'll put the code

Comment: Yes you have provided the function..but look can we run it? We need to runt he code...You need to provide us with `main()` and all those structure definition etc. Post that full code.

Comment: in main function i'm  just passing the two struct pointers into the arguments of the function, both of them are pointing at the first element of the adj list in the beginning.